# XML field position behind an inherited form [ Odoo ]

Tags: python, xml, odoo

I want to do this in XML

PICTURE

[image: 1]

This is my actual code. I want the field shipment_preferente to be just behind the last inherited data. Hope you can help me with this guys! :D

```
<record model="ir.ui.view" id="view_order_form_inherit">
        <field name="name">sale.order.form.inherit</field>
        <field name="model">sale.order</field>
        <field name="priority">15</field>
        <field name="inherit_id" ref="sale.view_order_form"/>
        <field name="arch" type="xml">
            <xpath expr="//button[@name='action_cancel']" position="after">
               ...
            </xpath>

            <xpath expr="//button[@name='action_cancel']" position="attributes">
                ...
            </xpath>


            <field name="payment_term_id" position="after">
                <field name="shipment_preference"/>
                <field name="business_unit_id" options="{'no_create': True, 'no_open': True}"/>
                <field name="order_type_id" options="{'no_create': True, 'no_open': True}"/>
            </field>
```

Comment: You should inherit the view that contains the inherited Delivery Address, and then place your field after the Delivery Address field. That should solve your issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Delivery address field ([partner_shipping_id](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/15.0/addons/sale/views/sale_views.xml#L322)) is defined in `order_view_form` inside the `partner_details` group.

You can use the following code to show your fields after the delivery address:

```
<field name="partner_shipping_id" position="after">
           
</field>
```

Or (The default position is [inside](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/master/developer/reference/backend/views.html#inheritance-specs)):

```
<group name="partner_details">
            
</group>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this way.

```
<xpath expr="//field[@name='partner_shipping_id']" position="after">
.....Your code
</xpath>
```